# Sitecore SXA Maps local Datasource for POI

Tags: sxa

We are developing an application to advertise real estate properties using **Sitecore 9.0.2** with **SXA 1.8.1**

Each property item should contain a Map with the `POI` pointing to the location of the property.

The problem that we are facing is that by default the `POI's` should be created under the Sitecore level Data folder - `{Site Tenant}/{Site}/Data/POIs`

If the application contains 1000 properties the `POI` multilist on the Map properties would contain 1000 `POIs` , which would make it difficult for the content author to search for the `POI` and select it on the property item

Any suggestions on how we could solve this?

May be have an Item level(local:) `POI` list ?

Answer (score 1):

Each page can become a Point of Interest if you will inherit from IPoi base template (`/sitecore/templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Geospatial/IPoi`). When you will assign this base template you will notice the following fields on your page:

[image]

Although, it won't be possible to assign such POI on the map using multilist field which is on the map as this fields expects POIs located under the Data item you should be able to assign that page (which in fact is now a POI) using RAW values:

[image]

You will need to assign some RAW values but you won't need to create additional POI items under the Data.